# Cant use gradlew outside his origin folder

Tags: java, gradle, weblogic

Well, my problem is really simple i have this structure for files

```
agendaWeb-ml
-> agenda-web-weblogic
   -> agendaweb-releases
      -> agendaweb-ear
      -> agendaweb-war
```

now im creating the gradlew inside agendaweb-ear something like this
gradle wrapper -p agenda-web-weblogic/agendaweb-releases/agendaweb-ear

The problem that i have is that i need to use this wrapper generated on the root of the proyect, in order to use some templates with azure pipelines

I already tried to create the wrapper on the root of the proyecto but i get some errors like build failed, because i dont know how to import the ear build.properties to the root proyect, i tried to make a settings.gradle with

```
include 'agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-war'
include 'agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-ear
```

but then i get

Error:(109, 0) Project with path ':agendaweb-war' could not be found in project ':agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-ear'.
Open File

thats because inside the build.gradle on the ear there is

```
dependencies {
    sshAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.9.2'

    deploy project(path:':agendaweb-war', configuration:'archives')
}
```

there is also in the ear a settings.gradle

```
def sharedRootDir = new File("../")
include ':agendaweb-war'
project( ':agendaweb-war' ).projectDir = new File(sharedRootDir,'agendaweb-war')
```

But when i am inside agendaweb-ear and throw ./gradlew test, it works

Pd: I know i can use gradle build -p agenda-web-weblogic/agendaweb-releases/agendaweb-ear to define the origin of the wrapper and execute from the origin, but i cant use that, i need the wrapper on the root folder

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem was inside build.gradle on agendaweb-ear in order to work has to be like this

```
dependencies {
    sshAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.9.2'
    deploy project(path:':agendaweb-war', configuration:'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-war', configuration: 'archives')
}
```

Now i can create a settings.gradle on root and set

include 'agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-ear'
include 'agenda-web-weblogic:agendaweb-releases:agendaweb-war'

This allows me to create the wrapper on root